In how many ways can we seat $3$ teachers and $8$ students in a row such that there are at least $2$ students between each teacher?
What is wrong with this (non)-solution: instead of $8$ students, think of $4$ pairs of students instead. Place the pairs in some fixed order. Then we can place a teacher in any of the $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ spots between the pairs (or at the ends). There are $\binom{8-2i}{2}$ ways to pick students $i$-th pair from the left, for each of $i = 0, 1, 2, 3$. Then there are $2^4 = 16$ ways to arrange the students inside the pairs. Finally, there are $3!$ ways to arrange the teachers. Therefore, the total count should be
$$\binom{5}{3}3!\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}2^4 = 2~419~200.$$
However, this is wrong. In fact, the correct answer is $\frac{7}{2} \cdot 2~419~200 = 8~467~200$. What doesn't this account for?

Let me first check whether the book answer is correct, then I shall check what is wrong with your answer
$-TSSTSST-$
Place 2 students each between the 3 teachers, then there are 4 students left to place in 4 bins, $\binom{7}{3}$ by stars and bars
Thus # of valid arrangements $= \binom738!3! =8467200$
So the book answer is correct, coming to your answer:
You have forced all students to be in pairs, and are restricting teachers  only to positions $0,3,6,9,12$ which is not correct.
For example, teachers could also be at positions $0,3,7/0,3,8/0,3,9/0,3,10/0,3,11/1,4,8/1,4,9\dots$ etc etc

Your explanation doesn't really explain why it is not correct.

I have added a few more words of explanation

Can you give an example arrangement which is not counted in my count?

For example, teachers could be at positions 0,3,7/0,3,8/0,3,9/0,3,10/0,3,11/$::$1,4,8... etc

I agree with both the answer and the analysis in the response of true blue anil.  An alternate (more long-winded) but more formal presentation is as follows:
This is a Stars and Bars problem in disguise.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
this article and
this article.
Now, it is clear from the posted question's official answer, that the $~3~$ teachers are each to be considered distinguishable from each other, and the $~8~$ students are each to be considered distinguishable from each other.
So, reserve the factor of
$$A = 8! \times 3!,$$
and then assume that the teacher's are indistinguishable from each other and the students are indistinguishable from each other.
Now, consider the following tableau:
- - T_1 - - T_2 - - T_3 - - 

The placement of the $~3~$ teachers creates $~4~$ islands, where the students can be distributed.  Reading the islands from left to right, let the respective sizes of these islands be represented by the variables $~x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3, ~x_4.~$
Then, under the (false) assumption that the teachers are indistinguishable and the students are indistinguishable, the desired enumeration is the number of solutions that satisfy the following constraints:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 8.$

$x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$2 \leq x_2, x_3.~$


The third bullet point above causes a problem because basic Stars and Bars theory requires that each variable be allowed to have the minimum value of $~0.~$ The routine fix is to set $~y_2 = x_2 - 2, ~y_3 = x_3 - 2.~$
So, the enumeration of the above three bullet points has been transformed to :

$x_1 + y_2 + y_3 + x_4 = 8 - 2 - 2 = 4.$

$x_1, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

$y_2, y_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$


By Stars and Bars theory, the enumeration of the above three bullet points is
$$\binom{4 + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{7}{3}.$$
Therefore, the final answer is
$$8! \times 3! \times \binom{7}{3}.$$
